# Create R boxplots of dataframe with another variable

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm looking to create a set of box plots where I create a bloxplot for each variable in sampledf1 against the single variable in sampledf2.

The actual use case is I've created a set of clusters with k-means and now want to see their distribution for each of the found clusters with each variable in the dataframe I'm using for clustering.

```
sampledf1 <- as.data.frame(replicate(6, sample(c(1:10,NA))))
sampledf2 <- as.data.frame(replicate(1, sample(c(21:30,NA))))
```

Then I want to see a box plot with each of the variables in sampledf1 paired with the only variable in sampledf2.

I would like to use something like:

```
sapply(boxplot(sampledf1~sampledf2$V1))
```

but this gives me this error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Anyway I could do this would dplyr would be great but I didn't see any functions that I could chain together to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`library(purrr)`'s `walk` works nicely when you start trying to pass formulas like this. `walk()` works like `sapply`, iterating over the elements in an object, just with more flexible syntax. The `.` refers to the iterated element from `names(sampledf1)`.

This will work to get each panel named by the column in `sampledf1` it represents:

```
library(purrr)    
par(mfrow = c(2,3))
purrr::walk(names(sampledf1), ~boxplot(sampledf1[,.]~sampledf2$V1, main = .))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nathan, is there anyway to add labels so I know which data each box plot has? Or is by order of variables in sampledf1 if I were to do a names(sampledf1)?

Comment: you're correct about the order it process in. you don't really need `map` here but it is the same function with different output, each useful depending on the scenario. I will edit in a labeled version

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `lapply` and `seq_along`. We iterate through the columns of `sampledf1` using `seq_along`. We can extract the variable names using our index, `i`, and the `names` function.

```
par(mfrow = c(2,3))
lapply(seq_along(sampledf1), 
       FUN  = function(i) 
           boxplot(sampledf1[,i] ~ sampledf2$V1, main = names(sampledf1)[i])
       )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use ggplot and facets, if you first reshape your data into long format

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
s.all = cbind(sampledf1, f2=sampledf2$V1)
s.long = melt(s.all, id = 'f2')
ggplot(s.long) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=f2, group=f2, y=value)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(s.long$f2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this as it's good to have more than one way to solve a problem and I'm learning plot.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` variant:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

sampledf1$X <- sampledf2$V1
ggplot(melt(sampledf1, id.vars="X", na.rm=T), aes(factor(X),value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap( ~ variable, nrow=2)
```

[image]